# How to organize code with random numbers in version control systems for analysis?

Tags: git, random, version-control

this is mostly a question about the organization of files in VCS such as git, but in order to give a good picture of my problem, here a quick introduction into the subject matter:

### Project Overview

I am working on a project, where neural-network-like probabilistic models are implemented and tested for different sets of parameters. Currently we are implementing in Python, although the problem might be relevant for different programming languages as well. The outcome is usually error measurements or graphs or something similar. Now at the moment our project is as follows:

- several people are working on the code base of the project and are implementing new features
- some other people are already trying to explore the behavior of the model for different parameter sets, i.e. figuring out for which parameter ranges the model shows qualitatively different behavior

At the moment we use git with GitHub as VCS with one master branch for the current stable version and one branch for every member of our team for active development. We exchange code by merging between branches and merge to master whatever seems a stable new feature.

One big problem in general is, that this is a research project without a clear project outline. Sometimes we are specifically fixing some bugs or implementing something planned with feature branches. But sometimes it is not clear, what exactly the next feature will be, or whether it is even possible to implement what we have in mind. Some of us are basically exploring the behavior of our model in a more or less structured way. I know. But that's how it is.

### Controlling Probabilistic Behavior

Our model is probabilistic on many levels. Various parts are initialized with random numbers and random numbers are also used while the model simulation is running.

Of course the best way to explore a probabilistic model is to let it run many times and statistically analize the results. Now for either demonstration purposes or in order to explore some specific behavior more deeply, you want the cases to be reproducible. Currently we do this, by setting the seeds of the random number generator at the beginning, like in numpy for python with

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.rand() # -> will always be 0.3745401188473625
b = np.random.rand() # -> will always be 0.9507143064099162
```

### Version Control Problems

We identified two issues with our current setting:

**1) How to store the snapshots for a specific behavior for later exploration?**

In order to label snapshots appropriately, we thought about both using branches and tags for specific experiments and found sets of parameters, like this:

```
* master
|
*---------------
|\              \
* * experiment1  * experiment2
| |              |
. * tag setting1 * tag setting1
. |              |
. * tag setting2 * tag setting2
```

The problem here is that as far as we understood, commits with tags are not meant to be changed later. Since we might work on these settings later, we would have to branch again from the specific tag.

Another way to go would be to use only branches, one for every found setting, such that every branch head corresponds to one working state of the system. But this would lead to a huge number of branches for all these things we identified.

So how would you organize a structure like this? Especially with the following problem in mind:

**2) How to merge changes into stored snapshots without changing probabilistic behavior**

Suppose one of our developers found a bug in the implementation that we had so far, or implemented a very useful feature and fixed it in the master branch. Now it might be very beneficial to use these changes for later analysis of one of the identified behaviors of the model. The problem is, that if the changes use random numbers, chances are that the behavior of the model will be completely different after merging.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.rand() # -> will always be 0.3745401188473625

# fixing some stuff here
c = np.random.rand()
# -> will be 0.9507143064099162 as was previously 'b'

b = np.random.rand()
# -> will now be 0.7319939418114051 and not anymore 0.9507143064099162

# ...
# code using 'b' will behave differently
```

This is really a big problem, because it means that:

- either we cannot (or only when not changing random numbers) use new features or apply bugfixes for the analysis of already identified interesting sets of parameters and random conditions
- or we have to identify these settings again and again after every change that uses random numbers

Of course the problem is still easy for the code shown here, involving only a few random calls. But in the models we have, random numbers will be generated many times and often the number of iterations is again influenced by the output of computations from other random-number-involving parts.

Do you have any recommendations concerning this issue?

Comment: It is not really predictive, we are trying to develop a new architecture with recurrent parts. So it is a dynamical system. Temporal behavior will be different, depending on specific settings, which we want to explore. It can also be run autonomously, without specific input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how we deal with these kind of development and experimental workflow.

## Separate code and experiments

Really, this is the most important thing to have in mind.
This is like badly designed computer simulations, where the simulated model and the simulation algorithm are completely intertwined. Having a separation of model and code is very important for a lot of reasons.

Similarly, separate your project into:

- one repository for the actual code development of the core algorithms
- one repository for each model

  Of course, the model may contain model-specific code, e.g. if how to set up the neurons in an ANN and code for parsing training data etc.
- one repository for each experiment

  An experiment is every analysis you make with a clear scientific question, like "How does optimisation *x* influence the classification accuracy?".
  Having such clear research question helps you in structuring your research, and also later publishing your research.

  Each experiment may, of course, involve multiple models and multiple data sets.

(*Note*: I am against storing data sets in version control software. Surely, a backup is required, but data sets should always be stored unmodified, and pre-processed data should be stored to different folders, and never overwrite the original data.)

## Use sub-modules for association and reproducibility

If you use `git`, you can use sub-modules for your experimental repository.
We use a directory structure similar to the following for experiments:

```
X-<date>-<title>/   # repository for experiment
|___ models/
|    |___ M1/       # submodule for M1's repository
|    |___ M2/       # submodule for M2's repository
|    |
|     ...
|___ code/          # submodule for your core algorithms
|___ data/          # a copy or link to your data sets
|___ experiment1.sh # script to run your experiment
|___ experiment2.sh # possibly some more sub-experiments
```

Sub-modules allow you refer to *a specific commit* (not branch or tag, literally a stable commit id) for both your models and code.
This way, you ensure reproducibility of your experiments.

Sub-modules are actually a part of your experiment's commit.
That is, every time you make changes to your experiment (e.g. `experiment1.sh`), you create a new commit.
Every time you update either your models or your code, you update the specific sub-module and create a new commit.
Would you like to revert back to a previous version, simply run `git checkout && git submodule update`.
All your sub-modules are automatically reverted to the commit at that state.

This answers your first question.

## Making experiments reproducible

First and foremost—also as a consequence of the above experimental structure—never set random seeds directly in our code.
Instead, pass them as command line arguments.
For example, in your `experiment1.sh`, call `code/my-tool --seed=42 models/M1/model.ann < input.dat`.
As `experiment1.sh` is under version control, you automatically ensure reproducibility.
This also conforms to the principle of separating code and data.

Concerning your second question, it is of course impossible to introduce new features (thus *changing behaviour*) and simultaneously keep the old behaviour.
You have to decide: is your experiment affected by the feature / bug fix?

Remember that experiments have a specific research question.
If you introduced a new feature you want to test, that may be worth a new experiment (or at least sub-experiment).
If you fixed a bug, than you want to make sure your results are consistent nevertheless—you fixed a bug and that bug caused your results to be invalid.

If you introduce a new feature, you do not want to *overwrite* your old results.
You are simply throwing some of your assets away!
Instead, use your results to compare how the change affected them. Maybe this gives you new insight into your model or algorithms.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good approach, thanks for sharing your experience! I'll wait for more responses and will accept your answer, if nothing better shows up.

Comment: This.  Model parameterization should not be wired into the code, it should be controlled by inputs.